# Migrate JSF RichFaces project from JSF 2.0 to 2.3

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, jsf-2.3

How to Migrate from JSF 2.0 to JSF 2.3 in existing EJB with RichFaces Project.
Please suggest the steps to be followed.

Answer (score 2):

This question is far too broad.

Official RF won't work with JSF 2.3. RF is very old and the last version is much older than JSF 2.3.

So the steps would be:

1. Upgrade to JSF 2.2.
2. Choose one:

   1. Stop with JSF 2.2.
   2. Remove RichFaces. Use something more modern like PrimeFaces.
   3. Try to use some forks of the original RF. For example the work of [Alberto Fernández](https://github.com/albfernandez/richfaces) which is avaible [on Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.albfernandez.richfaces/richfaces-core). But I don't know if that builds are really production ready (they seem to work with JSF 2.3).

Comment: If the question is too broad, you should vote to close it. Do not answer off topic (broad) questions. [answer]